# Repeatedly Being Asked to Install Command Line Tools

Tags: command-line, xcode

When I'm doing various development-related activities (such as initializing a git repository or installing packages in RStudio), I get repeatedly asked to install command line developer tools, even though I already have it installed.

I have a directory at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` which contains `Library`,`SDKs`, and `usr` folders.

If I go along with the popup and install command line tools (again), the popup simply appears again if I attempt whatever I was doing before (like initializing a git repo).

I've attempted running `xcode-select --install`, but I get an error saying

> Failed to locate 'clang', requesting installation of command line developer tools

and then that previously mentioned popup for installing command line tools reappears. I'm currently running MacOS Big Sur, but I'm fairly certain this was still an issue on the previous OS. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think there are many different reasons this issue can occur, and so there are many different possible solutions. However, what worked for me was opening **XCode** -> **Preferences** -> **Locations**, and then setting ***Command Line Tools*** to the current version of XCode (version 12.5 at the time of this post, located at */Applications/Xcode.app* for me). For whatever reason, there was no version selected until I manually set it via XCode Preferences.

Answer (score 261):

The following command worked

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Answer (score 42):

This **issue happened on** my **MacBook Air M1** machine after update **macOS Monterey 12.6** released recently and installing **Xcode CLI tools version 14.0**. If you use command line tools like Homebrew, you might have received the following error (the part below is just an excerpt of it):

```
clang: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find clang 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 34304: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'clang', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

Then you are told that you need to install additional tools, in my case clang.

**Here is the fix:**

1. Open Xcode app
2. Select the platforms you may or may not develop with (depends if you are actually an iOS/macOS developer or if you just use the CLI tools such as myself). Choose as few as possible as these take hard disk space!
3. Click download.
4. Close and re-open your Terminal and try your CLI tools again. That's it!

Keep in mind, tools for the platforms you chose will be downloaded in the background, which might take a bit.

**Update! Sep 9, 2022**
It seems the issue is not related to the architecture of the mac (M1 or Intel) or the Xcode version!

**Update! Nov 23, 2022**
Keep in mind that the Xcode tools when opening Xcode after further updates will need to be updated, but in my experience this should NOT affect the CLI tools.

Comment: I was facing this issue on a M1 MacBook Air and your steps fixed it! Super annoying issue and I kept downloading and installing following the prompts.

Comment: Coming back to this as it appears to have solved the issue with the prompt, but when going to System Preferences > Software Updates or running `softwareupdate -l` I am still being asked to install command line tools for Xcode 13.2, 13.4 and 14.0.

No idea why, tried installing them all and it keeps coming back.

Comment: It’s not related to 12.6 specifically – I just had the issue on my Mac Studio, which is still on 12.5.1 and hasn’t had any major updates installed for at least a month. I didn’t install or change anything Xcode-related recently, but this is a fairly new machine, and I don’t know if or when Xcode 14 was installed at all.

Comment: I'm getting this issue on both an M1 Macbook Air and a non-M1 Macbook Pro

Comment: I am also still being asked to install CLT for Xcode 13.2, 13.4 and 14.0, even after opening XCode or running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`.
My clang issue is fixed though.
It does seem to have happened after upgrading to 12.6

Comment: i upvoted this because i thought it fixed it.  later i found that it didn't.  the solution is `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Answer (score 12):

Based on the [thread in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1742439/macos-the-command-line-developer-tool-missing-after-updated-to-monterey-12-6) I ran

`xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`

That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well (after upgrading to macOS 12.6)

Comment: This worked for me with Intel MacBook Pro 2020 (MacOS 12.6 Monterey).

Answer (score 7):

Well I closed and opened Xcode again, it asked for an upgrade that I did and it all started working. Looks like they force you to update xcode tools by making your git stop working.

Comment: Just ran into this issue this morning, this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

It happened after I updated my OS to Monterey 12.6 from 12.5

Fix-
quit all terminal, IntelliJ wherever you are using shell.
Now open Xcode application, It will update or install something.
exit Xcode application and boom.
your git problem is fixed.
Enjoy !!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

The `instrument` command is deprecated in Xcode 13. Now you can use `xcrun xctrace list devices` to list devices.

Answer (score 2):

Installing manually from this link solved my problem:

- [Command Line Tools for Xcode 14](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20line%20tools)

I figure when Xcode can’t tell if the tools are installed from the gui, it’s easier than issuing `xcode-select` commands to pull down the package and start the installation.

Comment: What do you mean by manually? Can you pls describe in more detail because the the OP owner indicates, s/he's tried doing it manually, i.e. through the macOS command line interface, a.k.a. the Terminal app.

Comment: When i said manually, i mean just go that link (developer.apple.com/download) and install command line tools from there

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after migrating from *Intel* MacBook Pro —> *M1* MacBook Pro. Tried doing the accepted solution, but Xcode wouldn't open at all anymore.

**Reinstalling Xcode fixed these issues for me.**

1. Open **Launchpad** and search for *"Xcode"*
2. Click and hold the **Xcode** icon till an *"x"* appears
3. Click the *"x"* and then click ***Delete***
4. Open the **App Store** and search for *"Xcode"*
5. Install **Xcode** again
6. Open **Xcode**
7. Click ***Install*** if asked ***"Install additional required components?"***
8. After installation is complete, you can quit **Xcode**
9. Go to **System Preferences** —> **Software Update**
10. Click ***Update Now*** if there's an update available for **Command Line Tools for Xcode**
11. Restart **Terminal** / **iTerm**

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue. It just prompted again and again and installed again and again. I open `Xcode` and continue the installation. It was just gone.

So it may be a simple update installation of the `Xcode` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is asking again and again after reinstalling the command line using the command `sudo xcode-select --install`.

The solution that worked for me was to just open Xcode in my system and check if there are any updates required.

`OS version - macOS Monterey 12.6`

1. Open Xcode
2. If it will ask to install any component, just install it, else close the Xcode
3. Now reopen your terminal and try `git -v`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but none of the solutions above worked for me.

**tl;dr;** the solution is to run

```
sudo cp -R /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12* /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

which copies the older "MacOSX12" SDK into the Xcode 14 folders and seems to make everyone happy.

### Why this is happening

The error I was seeing relating to the `git` binary was:

```
2022-11-14 16:33:18.828 xcodebuild[20025:1284001] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/mc/tm26v4sd0pv1hncprqdff72h0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2022-14-11_16-33-0018.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk" cannot be located.
git: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
git: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -find git 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'git', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
```

In my case, Xcode updated to v14.1 and my Mac is running macOS 12.6. I'm not positive that those two things are related, but you can see above that the macOS SDK that xcodebuild is looking for is **MacOSX12.3.sdk**.

Running `xcode-select -p` returns `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, which is what Xcode 14 configured automatically. (Changing this via `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` fixes git, but breaks other things in subtle ways (like some CocoaPods commands).)
[image]

The key here seems to be to copy the older, "missing" macOS SDK version into the Xcode folder structure so that everyone is happy.

Ideally, there would be some way to just have git point to the updated macOS SDK version, but I haven't figured that one out yet. Maybe upgrading to Ventura would fix that, but I haven't had the time to test that yet...