# Keep getting prompted to install command line tools even after installing it

Tags: command-line, xcode, big-sur, apple-silicon

I think there is some issue with xcode and command line tools. I keep getting `The "make" command requires the command line tools. Would you like to install the tools now?`. I click "Install" let it install and then again i get the same popup asking to install again.

I see that tools are already available at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`[image].

This keeps getting triggered when I try to install npm dependencies of a project which has some subdependency that needs to be compiled with make triggering this.

How can I fix this?

I have seen similar questions being asked before:

- [Repeatedly Being Asked to Install Command Line Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415563/repeatedly-being-asked-to-install-command-line-tools)
- [Installing Xcode Command Line Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/installing-xcode-command-line-tools)
- [Big Sur keeps asking me to install Command Line Tools](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/419652/big-sur-keeps-asking-me-to-install-command-line-tools)

None of them seem to work

Comment: How did you install the CLT?

Comment: Installed Xcode 12.5.1, Xcode beta 13, also uninstalled them both and just installed command line tools using `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 5):

Try running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`, that solved the issue for me.

---

I was running into the same problem and found this question in my quest for answers. I found this message amongst the error output from my cli invocation:

```
Please ensure Xcode packages are up-to-date — try running 'xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch'.
```